# Query Parameter in Goal Funnel (step 2) Issue

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am trying to use this as my step 1 in the funnel but it is not working because it is a query parameter.

```
/onestepcheckout/?source=referral-email&medium=email&campaign=refer-a-friend
```

I have tried to escape the "?" using "\?" but I still don't get a conversion to register in my funnel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Equals to" in your goal configuration, then you cannot have query parameters in the path (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en-GB#dynamic). You can configure your goal with "Begins with" or use regex:

```
.*/onestepcheckout/\?source=referral-email&medium=email&campaign=refer-a-friend
```